# Users authentication in asp.net mvc 4 application on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, azure, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity

I'm building a website from scratch using ASP.NET MVC 4.
The application is hosted on Windows Azure.
It's a rather basic website application.

Next, I would like to authenticate my users.
The authentication requirements are, again, rather basic and straight forward.

I did some reading, and it seems that the best two options for me to achieve users authentication are:
1. ASP.NET SimpleMembership
2. Windows Azure Active Directory Access Control

Now, my questions are, which one should I choose? which one is more secured?

Answer (score 1):

It is dependent on what you want. WAAD -ACS gives you  option  to integrate various identity providers like google,yahoo etc or federate with Active directory services.
But if do not want such options and simply use your existing asp.net membership you can do that as well.